# Weight is storage for energy, right?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, everyday-life

Since weight is storage for energy, the light vehicle will have a slight advantage on the flat ground due to low stress applied on wheels meaning less friction pulling the vehicle back. When though, the ground has any amount of decline, the heavier vehicle will literally get pulled by gravity since its got its energy stored in weight, potentially making it faster. In summary, light vehicle wins on flat road and heavy vehicle wins on slanted road.

Comment: What goes down must come up?

Comment: Weight is not "storage for energy".  Weight is the force that earth's gravity applies to a mass (e.g., $W=mg$)

Answer (score 0):

But the lighter vehicle has a lower mass, so lower inertia.

If the friction forces on each vehicle are proportional to its weight, and hence proportional to its mass then neither vehicle has an advantage on a slope (assuming by "advantage" you mean a greater acceleration due to gravity).

On flat ground, if the same force is applied to both vehicles, then the lighter vehicle will have a higher acceleration because it has a lower mass.